# Multiple match with where clause in Neo4j Cypher gives error "Cannot match on a pattern containing only already bound identifiers"

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

We are using **neo4j-community-2.1.2**. Right now we have only **3 nodes Of Job label** in the database And we do Schema indexing on all fields that are used in this query .  Total DB hits **approx 40**
Query is ->

```
   PROFILE match (job1:Job) where (job1.jobType="Adhoc" or job1.jobType="Virtual") AND (job1.mode="Free" or job1.mode="Paid") with collect(job1) as jobs1    
    match (job2:Job)-[REQUIRED_SKILL]-(skill:Skill) where skill.name="Neo4j" and (job2 in jobs1) with collect(job2) as jobs2 
    match (job3:Job)-[REQUIRED_SKILL]-(skill:Skill) where skill.name="Java" and (job3 IN jobs2) with collect(job3) as jobs3 return jobs3
```

So we try to do something like that

```
match (job1:Job) where (job1.jobType="Adhoc" or job1.jobType="Virtual")
match (job1) where  (job1.mode="Free" or job1.mode="Paid") with collect(job1) as jobs1 return jobs1
```

Because result of first match goes to next match . So that in next filter there is only need to filter less number of nodes But we get this exception

```
Cannot match on a pattern containing only already bound identifiers (line 2, column 1)
"match (job1) where  (job1.mode="Free" or job1.mode="Paid") with collect(job1) as jobs1 return jobs1"
```

Optimize this Query

Comment: Issue resolve by upgrading   neo4j-community-2.1.2.  to  neo4j-community-2.1.7. of Cannot match on a pattern containing only bound identifiers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match `job1` twice, once it is matched you can use the same instance again (using `WITH`), or in this case, you can filter on both conditions using `AND`. Also your query would be simpler by replacing `OR` with `IN` inclusion test, like this:

```
match (job1:Job) 
  where job1.jobType in ["Adhoc", "Virtual"]
  and job1.mode in ["Free", "Paid"] 
return collect(job1) as jobs1
```